# Not able to edit items after using Sitecore SXA security role

Tags: sxa

I wanted to create security roles for sitecore users and use the script available in sxa by referring the below links -
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/set-up-security-for-a-tenant-and-a-site.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-security-roles.html

Then i created a user and assigned different role groups (site author, site designer, tenant author and tenant designer).
After logging in with that username i am not able to edit any items. And get below warning message on top of every item -
[image]

i verified the Language setting in each user profile which is set to default.

Below are the roles that got generated after running the script
[image]

Roles assigned to a user
[image]

Also i got below errors while setting up security role
Error at tenant level
[image]

Error at site level
[image]

Am i missing something ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am not able to edit any items. And get below warning message on top of every item -

This happens because by default the created roles do not define any Language Read/Write permissions. It's up to you to decide which languages should be available to these roles. Please set the Language Read/Write access permissions for your roles on the corresponding language items under /sitecore/system/Languages.

> Also i got below errors while setting up security role Error at tenant level

it looks like some items expected by the script were missing under /sitecore/Forms item. However , there seems to be no problem with the role creation